# Can a destructed assignment return any number of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, destructuring

I have a series of Storybook stories, and a function that returns a `ComponentStory` object. I'm trying to think of a succinct way to clone a bunch of stories, without having something like this:

```
export const Default = bindStory(Template);
export const WithError = bindStory(Template);
export const AnotherOne = bindStory(Template);
```

Some of the files have 20, 30, stories in them, so this could get unwieldy and not very DRY. I was wondering if there would be a way to define it like this:

```
export const [Default, WithError, AnotherOne] = bindStories(Template);
```

And then apply the `.args` to those individual objects. The issue would be ensuring the `bindStories` function always returns enough instances of the `ComponentStory` object.

Comment: `getObjects` has no information about what the caller is intending to do, _if anything_, with whatever it returns.

Comment: No, `getObjects` won't know that--getObjects just returns an array; the assignment is completely separate from the call.

Comment: Why would it be a problem that `second` is `undefined`? Just test for that before you branch into code that would need it to run, and then just... not run that if `second === undefined`?

Comment: I'm curious to know what use case would *need* something like this.  The function simply returns its result.  It doesn't know or care what consuming code does with that result.  Why should it?  Why does that responsibility belong to the function?

Comment: Agree with @David. Can you provide some use cases? Why/how would the code handle different cases with varying number of destructured variables?

Comment: Why not just get the whole array back and then check its length? You don't *have* to use destructuring, and this is a great example of when it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @David Apologies, I was trying to keep it generalised for ease. I have added my specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can make use of infinite iterators. [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#using_array_destructuring_on_any_iterable) works on any iterable and so an infinite iterator allows for as many objects as you like. This means you don't need to pass `length` and the variables will never be undefined.

```js
function* getObjects() {
  const object = {
    lorem: 1
  };

  while (true) {
    yield { ...object };
  }
};

const [first, second, third, fourth] = getObjects();
console.log({
  first,
  second,
  third,
  fourth
});
```